# Does AOSP support MIPS architecture, for Android Marshmallow?

Tags: android, android-source

Is it possible to build Android Marshmallow ROM for MIPS architecture using AOSP, or any other repository?

I've got an impression that Google dropped support of MIPS architecture from AOSP, starting from Android 6.0, because they've dropped OpenSSL from AOSP in favor of their own fork, BoringSSL, and BoringSSL can be compiled only for ARM and X86. [Imagination Technologies](https://community.imgtec.com/developers/mips/android/) website also does not have Android 6.0 sources.

Answer (score 1):

[Support for MIPS architecture is removed from Android NDK r17](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/revision_history.html), so that's it, Android on MIPS is officially dead.